# How can I find needed info from this html with python?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
<bg-quote class="value negative" field="Last" format="0,0.00" channel="/zigman2/quotes/203558040/composite,/zigman2/quotes/203558040/lastsale" data-last-stamp="1624622210990" data-last-raw="675.17">675.17</bg-quote>
```

I'm doing a web scraping app and I need to get the value of data-last-raw in that html of an web page, but I have no clue how to access that. I have no knowledge of html so this is kinda hard. What is that data-last-raw? Some kind of variable?

I'm doing this with python, requests and beautifulsoup.

Here's my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import tkinter as tk


class Scraping:

    @classmethod
    def get_to_site(cls, stock_name):
        sitename = 'https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/tsla' + stock_name
        site = requests.get(sitename, headers={
            "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate",
            "Accept-Language":"en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,ml;q=0.7",
            "Connection":"keep-alive",
            "Host":"www.marketwatch.com",
            "Referer":"https://www.marketwatch.com",
            "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1",
            "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.119 Safari/537.36"
        })
        src = site.content
        Scraping.get_price(src)
        
    @classmethod
    def get_price(cls, src):
        soup = BS(src, "html.parser")
        price_holder = soup.select_one("")
        price = price_holder.getText()
        print(price)

class GUI:
    pass

Scraping.get_to_site('tsla')
```

Comment: Anything that is 'assigned' a value in the element tag declaration is called an attribute. Technically, classes and styles are attributes can be too, because you assign value to them like this: `style=""`. Similarly, `data-last-raw` is an attribute of the element tag. I'm not sure about the specifics of the framework you're using, but try searching something along the lines of "get attribute from element using xxx framework"

Comment: Are you sure that your data is HTML?? I think it might be an XML file instead.